# How does Transfer encoding works over HTTPS connection

Tags: http, networking, https

I have a question on how setting `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` works when the connection is `HTTPS`. What I read from the internet is, `Transfer-Encoding` is Hop to Hop header. Suppose if I set the `Transfer-Encoding` header, how come the intermediate HOPS identify whether the header is set to `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding`. There is high possibility that, the intermediate HOP might close the connection.

Comment: An HTTPS proxy won't even see the content, so it won't have a chance to change the headers.

Comment: Ok. My question is , if I set the transfer encoding to chunked , how does the proxy knows when to close the socket connection as it would not know whether it has content length or transfer encoding

Comment: It just closes when the upstream server does, or the downstream client. It doesn't need any intelligence of its own. It just copies bytes in both directions simultaneously until end of stream once the CONNECT operation is complete.